# vue3 is not installing globaly

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm-install, vuejs3

Hello when i try to install vue3 globally using this command "npm install -g @vue/cli" then it shows the following error:

> vue : File C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 cannot be loaded
> because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
> information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
>
> - vue --version
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need use root privilege to run the command or give execution permission

use open as administor to opnen the terminal